# How long can kill -9 take

Tags: linux, kill, posix, process-management

I am writing a custom process manager, that executes commands and monitors their execution. On their termination sometimes I want to terminate some running processes and execute other processes. I want to do it in a blocking, one-threaded manner.

My main concern is that my program uses `kill -9 (SIGTERM)` to kill its child processes. I've read that `kill -9` is supposed to terminate the process immediately, but I would like to know whether there are any underlying issues with my solution, and if terminating a program via SIGKILL can take a significant amount of time (say, greater than 1-2 seconds).

I would also like to know the underlying OS internals of sending SIGKILL are, and what exactly happens when I send this signal to a child process.

I would appreciate any help, insight, or feedback regarding my concern.

Comment: I can imagine kill -9 taking minutes if the system is heavily stressed, i.e. there's very little available RAM, a lot of stuff is swapped out, thus killing a process is not so instant any longer.

Comment: AFAIK the system call should return pretty much immediately, it just marks the signal in the receiving process. But having the killed process actually terminate might take indefinitely, e.g. on Linux with processes in the `D` state (due to NFS or whatever)

Comment: using `kill -9` (`SIGKILL`) by default is terrible as it gives programs no chance to cleanup various resources they might have open (temporary files, shared memory, database connections, etc). the call could otherwise take a very long time on a very busy system... maybe you are patient, or maybe linux finally crashes, or maybe you poke it with the reset paperclip you've hung on the rack doors for that purpose?

Comment: @thrig, yes, I understand, that SIGKILL is considered a bad practice, but in my domain, it is the least of two evils: sometimes it may be critical to terminate the child process as soon, as possible

Comment: @Artem `kill -9` doesn’t involve swapping in any of the pages owned by the killed process; they are just dropped.

Comment: The kill -9 command itself involves paging and a lot of IO, so you cannot be further from the truth. Also, I've been in situations when the system was heavily stressed, and oh boy kill -9 is not instant at all.

Comment: Another observation is that if you try to `kill -9` something that has lost `I/O` functionality (e.g. writing to disk and the disk failed) can take forever - literally. That process (and the kill) won't go away until you reboot.